# How can I get value from firebase for specific key at specified child without using childEventListener?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing an android app in which I need to retrieve value from Firebase database which I manually added before. The data stored in Firebase database is not symmetrical, which is why I can not use a class object.

I want to do something similar to following codes.

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseRef;
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseRef= firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("child").child("child2");
String value = databaseRef.getValue("key");
//In above line I want to retrieve string at child → child2 → key:"value"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While recommended, you don't *have to* use custom Java classes for getting values out of Firebase. You can also read the primitive types directly, as I'll show below. But no matter whether you use custom classes or primitive types, you will always have to [use a listener to read data from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#listen_for_value_events):

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference databaseRef;
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
databaseRef= firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("child").child("child2");
databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "listener canceled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};
```

You can attach a listener to any level in your JSON tree this way, and Firebase will synchronize all the data below that point into the [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot). Then you can get it from the snapshot with its `getChild()` and `getValue()` methods. So for example to read everything under `child`, but only print `child2`:

```
databaseRef= firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("child");
databaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String value = dataSnapshot.getChild("child2").getValue(String.class);
        Log.i(TAG, "child2: "+value);
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "listener canceled", databaseError.toException());
    }
};
```

The second snippet reads more data from the database, but then only extracts `child2` from the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set ValueEventListener and take a datasnapshot as written in the Firebase documentation

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
    Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Post failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
}
};
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(postListener);
```